# Google collections - modifiable iterator from collections.filter?

Tags: java, guava

The collection that is returned from Collections2.filter is unmodifiable, and so is its iterator. 
Is there anything similar that will return my a filtered live view of a collection, but with a modifiable iterator? I need to use `remove()` method on the iterator.

Thanks.

Comment: That doesn't sound like a good use case for `filter`, which comes from functional programming and traditionally returns a read-only collection. Why not use a plain old `for` loop?

Comment: The list is held somewhere else also, so I want that removing object in one place will be reflected somewhere also - that is why live view is important for me. For loop won't do

Comment: @duduanar: Why wouldn't an explicit loop do? I think we need more information about your specific use case. Also remember that you can always assign the collection returned by `filter` back to the original source. Guava emphasizes the concept of immutability a lot, which contradicts your requirement.

Comment: FYI, the way `Collections.filter` works -- or any filter, frankly -- means that you can't remove elements.  In particular, the backing iterator might have moved forward by the time you call `remove()`, which could lead to seriously unexpected behavior if it works at all.

Comment: Louis, I don't understand how the backing iterator could unexpectedly move? `Collections2` creates it, no-one else gets a direct reference.

Comment: `Collections2.filter(collection, predicate).iterator().hasNext()` may have to advance the backing iterator past several elements to see if any of the remaining elements in the iterator satisfy the predicate, but after the backing iterator has been advanced, `remove()` will no longer remove the previously returned element.

Answer (score -1):

How about `new ArrayList(Collections2.filter(...))`? If you insist using filter for some reason.

By the way, `Collections2.filter` is not unmodifiable. It's collection which only allows `Predicate` logic elements.

Comment: This would copy the contents of `Collections2.filter()` into a new `ArrayList`. Removing elements from that list would not remove them from the original collection.